# Kendo controls render in Debug mode only

Tags: kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have created a MVC 3 site using Kendo.  When I go into Debug mode the Kendo controls render with no problem.  When I public the project to my IIS7 server the controls do not render.  Here is what I have in the layout file to reference the kendo javascript files and other javascript files.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/common.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/json2.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2013.1.319/jquery.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2013.1.319/kendo.web.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2013.1.319/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2013.1.319/kendo.culture.en-US.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Compare the source of your site that does work to the source of your site that doesn't and figure out what is different.

Comment: I figured it out.  The previous programmer was using templates and for some reason did not include them into the project to be uploaded when the project was published.